# Simple clustering method for following statement

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset:

[image]

I want to apply the clustering technique to create clusters of every 5 minutes' data and want to calculate the average of the last column i.e. percentage congestion.

How to create such clusters of every 5 minutes? I want to use this analysis further for decision making. The decision will be made on the basis of average percentage calculated.

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple aggregation, and not *clustering*.

Use a loop, read one record at a time, and every 5 minutes output the average and reinitialize the accumulators.

Or round ever time to the 5 minute granularity. Then take the average of now identical keys. That would be a SQL GROUP_BY.